# How to preserve headers case while calling Rest API using java.net.http.HttpClient

Tags: java, rest, http-headers

I am using below code snippet to test one of the client API.
Eventhough I am sending header as "userID" but it is received as "userid" at clients end and its failing with 403 error since headers are checked in a case sensitive manner at client side.

Please find the code snippet below

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://example.com/xyz"))
                .header("userID", "test_user")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .method("POST", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{\n\t\"data\": \"test\",\n\t\"sign\": \"test\"\n}"))
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = null;
        try {
            response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.body());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println(response.body());
```

Is there anyway to preserve the header case while calling API using java code.

Comment: Hi, headers are technically case insensitive see here for official documentation (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#appendix-A.20). However, if you have implemented an API that for some reason checks case then you might want to consider changing that, since apparently many firewalls block non-conforming HTTP requests. 

The documentation of HttpRequest.Builder states that: "An implementation may choose to restrict some header names or values, as the HTTP Client may determine their value itself." This probably makes what your attempting impossible given your current implementation.

Comment: Thanks @StenHealey for your suggestion. Its a client API and i donot have any control on that implementation.

Comment: Help will be appreciated

Comment: The only suggestion I can really make is to create a custom HTTP request using sockets. This is a drastic option and I absolutely do not recommend it as a viable long term solution. This may still not work since a lot of technologies are going to auto-cast your headers or ignore case altogether. Sorry that I couldn't be of more assistance, but your essentially ignoring official HTTP guidelines.